# Why does $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is used in my textbook without any real explanation. Is this something that follows from Lagrange?

Lagrange: If $H \subseteq G$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then $$|G|=|G/H||H|$$

Other than this it is used several times without reference to anything.

Thanks!

Comment: It follows from Lagrange and from the elementary fact that $a=\frac{b}{c}$ follows from $ac=b$. (Note those are all orders or indexes, so they are all nonzero.)

Comment: See Diego's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346783/group-theory-left-right-h-cosets-and-quotient-sets-g-h-and-g-setminus-h?rq=1)

Comment: I find this question quite extraordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that:

1. All cosets are in bijection with $H$, hence they all have the same number of elements, $|H|$;
2. They make up a *partition* of $G$,

   so you can apply the *shepherd's principle*.

Comment: Can you explain the "shepherd's principle"? I've never heard of it and a quick google didn't turn anything up.

Comment: It says that when a shepherd wants to count  his sheep, he counts the total number of legs, and divides by $4$ (supposing  there's no cripple sheep ;–). It is quite close to the rule of sum in combinatorics.

Comment: So it says that if every object has $k$ things and there are $n$ objects then there are $nk$ things?

Comment: Yes, $ $ exactly